# How to register a domain that has expired

Tags: domain-registration, domains

There's a domain that I would like to register, but everywhere is saying it is taken. When I do a who.is search for the domain it says that it expired Jan 01 2018... how do i go about getting it registered?

Comment: The answer hugely depends on the TLD, so by not giving any detailed information, you can not get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Look at [What to do if the domain name you want is taken](https://domains.google/learn/what-to-do-if-the-domain-name-you-want-is-taken.html#/)?

Comment: Thanks Sunny... I have contacted godaddy and they say that although the domain is expired the registry have decided to hold onto it for now.. they don't know when it will be released.. which is annoying... but hey ho... thanks for your response.

Comment: Namecheap does the same thing - they retain the domain for a grace period after expiration and let you have first shot at renewing it.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz.. that's what I thought.. however godaddy claim it is the registry rather than than the registrar or individual holding back the domain.

Comment: @jon Frankly, if GoDaddy told me the sky was blue, I'd not only have to check, but I'd *expect* some weird meteorological phenomenon to have somehow changed it to rainbow colors.

Comment: The grace period after deletion is handled by the registry, not any given registrar. And @jon since you are not even saying the TLD at least or even the fullname you restrict a lot how people could give you good answers.